# When I use ansible module expect, I got this msg: The pexpect python module is required

Tags: ansible, pexpect

I am trying to use ansible to deploy our system. I used expect module in yml file and try using `ansible-playbook` to run it and got this error:

> fatal: [192.168.100.132]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed":
>   true, "msg": "The pexpect python module is required"}

Then I downloaded the pexpect-4.2.1 package from pypi.python.org and install it by "python setup.py install".
But it doesn't work and error never changed.
What should I do to deal with the error ?

Some code from yml file:

```
- name: auth root
  expect:
    command: mysql_secure_installation
    responses:
      'Enter password for user root:': '{{password.stdout}}'
      'New password:': 'dtise123'
      'Re-enter new password:': 'dtise123'
      'Do you wish to continue with the password provided\?\(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) :': 'y'
      'Remove anonymous users\? \(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) :': 'y'
      'Disallow root login remotely\? \(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) :': 'y'
      'Remove test database and access to it\? \(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) :': 'y'
      'Reload privilege tables now\? \(Press y\|Y for Yes, any other key for No\) :': 'y'
    echo: yes
```

I downloaded the pexpect-4.2.1.tar.gz from pypi.python.org and did like this:

```
mv pexpect-4.2.1.tar.gz /usr/local/src/
cd /usr/local/src
tar zxvf pexpect-4.2.1.tar.gz
cd pexpect-4.2.1
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Where did you install pexpect?

Comment: I added the answer in the question.Please help me!

Comment: When I asked where, I meant on which machine.

Comment: I am sorry. I installed it on the ansible host. Do I need to install it on each node machine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I installed it [pexpect] on the Ansible host. Do I need to install it on each node machine?

Yes, modules are executed on target machines and prerequisites (if they exist) must be installed on them.

Comment: Thank you very much. When I installed pexpect and ptyprocess in the target machine it really does work !