# Using Ansible Playbook run an interactive script and pick the response correctly

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I need to run an interactive script, to get the application client installed on my servers using Ansible playbook. During the installation it asks for IP address, port number, server name, username and password.

```
- name: Install application client
  hosts: all
  tasks:  Run the script
  - name: Execute the user interactive script                                                                  
    command: /home/ansible/install.sh
```

Below prompts for the responses

```
Enter IP: **1.2.3.4**
Enter Port: **440**
Enter Server Name: **AppServerName**
Connectivity Succeeded
Enter Username: **UserName**
Enter Password: **xxxx**
```

I would like to know how we can predefine these responses in playbook itself and pick it when it prompts for?

Thanks,
Jean Thomas

Comment: Please see if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59999716/how-to-pass-input-to-interactive-command-using-ansible) helps.

Comment: Use the [`expect` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html). As stated in this documentation, this is made for simple scenario (which seems to be your case). For anything more complex, run expect directly with the command|shell module.

Comment: Thanks @Seshadri_C, however i am getting  '''FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Insufficient version of pexpect installed (2.3), this module requires pexpect>=3.3. Error was 'module' object has no attribute 'runu'"}'''
I am having |Redhat server and 2.3 is only available to install. Any workaround for this please?

Comment: You could install later version of `pexpect` with `pip install` or through tarball like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845748/when-i-use-ansible-module-expect-i-got-this-msg-the-pexpect-python-module-is-r). Or use `shell` module with expect as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56129841/13968097).

Comment: I created a playbook as below. 
    - name: Install client
      shell: /script.bsx
        expect "Enter IP:"
        send "1.2.3.4\n"
        expect "Enter Port:"
        send "1234\n"
        expect "Enter Serve Name:"
        send "serverName\n"
However my log files shows like it could not receive the IP address. Also I would like to know how we can set no timeout or bit longer timeout between each expect?

2020-10-05_165434 NetCat already installed on this OS.
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: _You must specify a host to connect to. QUITTING._

Comment: @Seshadri_C , Any idea if there is an option to set no timeout in between each expect and why that IP could not be picked up from above example? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding this as an answer. As the shell script you are trying to run "expects" some responses, we need to supply those responses using Linux `expect`.

Let's say we have a simple shell script `test.sh` like below. It takes IP address and Port, then runs the `nc` command:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "IP address:"
read ip_addr

echo "Port:"
read port

nc -vz $ip_addr $port
```

To run this script from Ansible with `expect`, then we would have a simple playbook as below:

```yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    send_ip_addr: "1.2.3.4"
    send_port: "22"

  tasks:
  - shell: |
      spawn ./test.sh
      expect "IP address:"
      send -- "{{ send_ip_addr }}\n"
      expect "Port:"
      send -- "{{ send_port }}\n"
      expect eof
    args:
      executable: /usr/bin/expect
```

Linux `expect` is a scripting language in itself, and what we have above is a simple `.exp` script within the Ansible `shell` task. I think we *only* can set `timeout` at the beginning. See the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expect.1.html) for all supported options.

There is also a useful `autoexpect` command that will create a `script.exp` script for us. Example:

```
autoexpect test.sh
```